# Which server create CSR if there's multiple forwards

Tags: ssl, tomcat

My server environment:

I have a website call **abc.com.** I've created **subdomain call demo** using **Advanced DNS Zone Editor via cPanel** and it's point to my static IP 123.123.123.123

```
demo.abc.com => 123.123.123.123 (winbox installed)
```

Then I have another local tomcat server with 192.168.1.123 and I have a port forward setup `123.123.123.123:80 into 192.168.1.123`

now when I type `demo.abc.com` it's going to execute my `192.168.1.123` hosted tomcat website.

Now I need to install **SSL** on the **https://demo.abc.com**

which server do I need to use for creating the CSR file ?

123.123.123.123  or 192.168.1.123 ?

Comment: You can make your redactions easier to read if you follow instructions here: https://meta.serverfault.com/a/6063/250204

Comment: all IP's and domain names are fake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it is best to generate the CSR on the machine that will actually use the certificate - its the only machine that will hold the certificate key in any case, hence this way you are not increasing your risk of certificate compromise.

In your example, the locally-addressed server runs a publicly-accessible web server anyway, so with minimal changes, you can enable TLS.

1. Add Forwarding for port 443 (analogue to what you have for port 80)
2. Generate the certificate request on the locally-addressed machine
3. Get signed certificate
4. Add it to the web server that already serves the `demo` subdomain

*However*, I highly recommend that you read up about the more common setup anyway.

Which avoids poking through the firewall in such generic ways. Typically, you would not port-forward, but instead proxy using a common web server - in that case the certificate would go in the machine with the globally routable address, while the applications in private address space would never directly talk to clients or deal with public certificates.